# DSum in access not Working

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with the workers ID "tblWORKERS" and a Query with all the transactions each worker made "QryTRANSACTIONS".

QryTRANSACTIONS:

```
WorkerID|TransactionDate|AMOUNT
    A   |   01/01/2017  | $500
    B   |   01/01/2017  | $600
    A   |   01/16/2017  | $300
    B   |   01/16/2017  | $700
    A   |   02/01/2017  | $1,200
    B   |   02/01/2017  | $1,300
    A   |   02/16/2017  | $900
    B   |   02/16/2017  | $2,000
    A   |   03/01/2017  | $5,000
    B   |   03/01/2017  | $8,000
```

So now I need the sum of the transactions of WorkerID A that happened on february
so I did this:

```
ExtrasSimples: DSum("AMOUNT","QryTRANSACTIONS","WorkerID = '" & 
[tblWORKERS]![WorkerID] & "' AND 
TransactionDate >= #" & DateSerial(2017,2,1) & "# AND 
TransactionDate <= #" & DateSerial(2017,2,28) & "#")
```

The correct answer is: $2,100 (row no. 5 & 7) but Access gives me: $2,500 (rows no. 3, 5 & 7).. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why that is happening, but if you want the whole month, the days are irrelevant. Try:

```
ExtrasSimples: DSum("AMOUNT","QryTRANSACTIONS","WorkerID = '" & 
[tblWORKERS]![WorkerID] & "' AND 
Format(TransactionDate,'yyyymm') = '" & Format([TransactionDate], "yyyymm") & "'")
```

Comment: You were quick. See edit for dynamic year/month parameter.